# Why am I unable to use some packages in Rstudio?

Tags: r

My Rstudio version is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRKz5.png)
Running on R version 3.5.2 (64 bits). I need to use caTool for data analysis but I was unable to find and install the package.

Also, when I tried to install HH package, the console just writes

`Error: package ‘latticeExtra’ required by ‘HH’ could not be found In addition: Warning message:package ‘HH’ was built under R version 3.5.3`

Last one,
When I attempt to use DMwR package

`Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘DMwR’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):there is no package called ‘caTools’In addition: Warning message:package ‘DMwR’ was built under R version 3.5.3`
Does this mean caTool is like a dependency for DmwR? How do I fix these issues? I was told to downgrade my Rstudio Version but to which version of Rstudio?

Comment: Is package `caTools` installed? Try running `find.package("caTools")`. There is also `help("installed.packages")`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas-ReinstateMonic  Thanks for the reply. The issue is I cannot even find the package in the install list

Comment: The latest version of caTools requires R version 3.6.0 or newer.  It's useful to check the package information page on CRAN when you have issues like this (https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=caTools).

Comment: If you cannot update R then you can find an appropriate version of the package [here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/caTools/). It seems it should be `caTools_1.17.1.2 (2019-03-06)`

Comment: @RuiBarradas-ReinstateMonic Thank you I will try that.